# MongDB - queries a large collection

Tags: python, mongodb, bigdata

I have 40 MM documents in my MongoDB collection (e.g. db.large_collection)

I want to get all the distinct User_ID.

I have created an Index on the field user_id but when I try to execute, it returns an error.

```
> db.large_collection.count()
39894523

> db.clean_tweets4.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "sampled_tourist.clean_tweets4"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "user_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "user_id_1",
    "ns" : "sampled_tourist.clean_tweets4"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "coordinates" : 1
    },
    "name" : "coordinates_1",
    "ns" : "sampled_tourist.clean_tweets4"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "timestamp_ms" : 1
    },
    "name" : "timestamp_ms_1",
    "ns" : "sampled_tourist.clean_tweets4"
}
```

]

But when I run

```
    db.clean_tweets4.find({},{user_id:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2be"), "user_id" : NumberLong("2246342226") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2bf"), "user_id" : NumberLong("2289817236") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2c0"), "user_id" : 1904381486 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2c1"), "user_id" : NumberLong("3044032705") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2c2"), "user_id" : NumberLong("3407958364") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9d278776f4b56ee4af2"), "user_id" : 1566025975 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f7ab78776f4b56ea55c6"), "user_id" : 15857879 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede28f"), "user_id" : NumberLong("3394102511") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede293"), "user_id" : 1376377652 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede294"), "user_id" : 352385989 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede295"), "user_id" : NumberLong("2383622643") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede29c"), "user_id" : 152362163 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2a0"), "user_id" : 1446113954 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2a1"), "user_id" : 1893437088 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2a2"), "user_id" : 67121578 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2a3"), "user_id" : 1714137770 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5790f9a178776f4b56ede2a4"), "user_id" : 52806609 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you check out `distinct`? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Yes. But, that kept crashing on me and saying that it couldn't handle the memory. Any other ideas?

Comment: What error does it return?

Answer (score -1):

find({}); means it returns everything. 
This is what you want.

```
db.collection.find({user_id:1});
```

Comment: I guess i'm confused on what you are trying to do. Is there a place to view your entire collection.